# Determine the number of three-digit numbers that are divisible by 3

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Determine the number of three-digit numbers that are divisible by 3 and that you can form with 3 different numbers among 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8

I found 5 numbers or 5 different ways with a sum that is divisible by 3. And each of them has 6 combinations because 3* 2* 1=6 so the total number should be 5*3=30 three-digit numbers that are divisible by 3. But I'm not sure if it's right or if there's a better solution.

Comment: $5 \times 6 = 30$. Yes seems the right way to go about it.

Comment: Max sum of $3$ digits divisible by $3$ you can get from the given numbers is $15$. So you only have to check what $3$ digits sum to $6, 9, 12$ or $15$.

Comment: You should get $7$ triples giving $42$ numbers. I see no better way than checking all triples for divisibility by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}2,5,8&\equiv -1\pmod 3\\3,6&\equiv 0\pmod 3\\1&\equiv 1\pmod 3\end{align}$$
There are $3\times 2\times 1=6$ ways to select one number from each group and $1$ way to select three numbers from a single group, for a total of $7$ combinations.

There are $3!=6$ permutations of each combination, giving a total of $7\times 6=42$ three-digit numbers.